# Analytics.js track webapp multiple domains

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics

We have a webapplication hosted on our servers.
Some customers use our predefined (sub)domains and some other customers use their own domain (paid users).

As I want to track total usage of all established webapps I'd like to use the same tracking code on all domains?
The customers can add their own tracking code too (I've already figured out how to do this).

So is it possible to do it like this?

```
sub1.domain.com -> UA-XXXXXXX-1
sub2.domain.com -> UA-XXXXXXX-1
customer3.com -> UA-XXXXXXX-1
customer4.com -> UA-XXXXXXX-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the best tutorial for it

http://www.ericmobley.net/guide-to-tracking-multiple-subdomains-in-google-analytics/

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#multipleDomains

The trick is the cookies domain property:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {'cookieDomain': 'example.com'});
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', auto);
```

most of the time you setup as auto. Check the doc for more info about the cookieDomain.

> To Tracking Across a Domain and Its Subdomains
>
> As mentioned above, a default setup of Google Analytics is designed to
>   track content and visitor data for a single domain, such as
>   www.example.com. This means that even if you manage both a domain and
>   a sub-domain, you must make modifications to the tracking code in
>   order to share visitor data across both domains.

Display Subdomains In Your Analytics Data using custom filters and Set Up A View For Each Subdomain (Optional).